# Ember Power Select: select values with Gauge & Selenide

Tags: java, ember.js, selenide

I test an Ember website with Gauge and Seleneide (Java).
-> I'd like to select some values in a Ember Power-Select component. How can I achieve that?

I am able to get the Power-Select component as a `SelenideElement` object, but setting a value with `setValue` is useless. Power-Select seems to use an `input` field that is converted to a `ul,li` list once I select a value. To be honest, I'm completely lost.
Thx.

Comment: add html example of your element, or lint to site with info what element to search. Will try to help

Answer (score 0):

Try to behave like a real user.

If it is a select you need following:

```
SelenideElement powerSelectComponent = $(xpath);

powerSelectComponent.click();
$(By.text("text of option you want to click to")).click
```